# Google Map Web Service working on local but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a problem with a Javascript request to the Google Map Api Web Service : if I have the HTML file on my computer it works, but it doesn't work online.

Here's the code :

```
url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Senador+Francisco+Quindimil+Y+Carabobo+Por+Carabobo,Ciudad+Autonoma+de+Buenos+Aires,Argentina&sensor=false';

$.get(url, function(data) {
  $('#result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
}, 'text');
```

This sample is just supposed to load the "data" in the "result" element. When it is offline, the "data" has text, but not when it is online.

Sample here : [Online Web Service Test](http://stoeffler.cc/reverse_geocoder/test.html)

Could one of you guys help ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You'll need to setup a [server-side proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) (HTTP handler) to hit up Google Maps out in the wild.

Comment: Thank you ! For those who experience the same problem I recommend this resource to make the proxy http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Comment: @Julien You are welcome!  I have updated my answer to include a link to that page.  That is a very good explanation of the problem.

Comment: Hey Julien, can you share the codings that you made for it to work on live server?

Comment: @ricky Why don't you read the link he posted?  The article includes a [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/samples/proxy/php_proxy_simple.txt) to a PHP proxy.